# Solve the wave equation and use the initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the initial value problem $u_{t} + 4u_{x} =0$ ; $u(0,x) = 5e^{-x^2}$. then write the explicit formula.

Solution:

Using the method of characteristic. $$\frac{dx}{dt} = 4$$ $$dx=4dt$$ to get an ordinary differential. integrate with respect of the variable in each sides. to get $$ x= 4t + c$$ this C is my characteristic variable that change the waves. i will call it $\psi$ so $$\psi = x-4t$$ now using my initial condition $u(0,x) = 5e^{-x^2}$ to get the explicit form i get $$u(t,x)=5e^{-(x-4t)^2}$$. Now if i were to look for $u(0,x)$,  $u(1,x)$,  $u(3,x)$. $$u(0,x)=5e^{-(x)^2}$$.  $$u(1,x)=5e^{-(x-4)^2}$$,  $$u(2,x)=5e^{-(x-8)^2}$$.

I am not feeling to confident about this, so i was wondering if that was the right approach, and also if there is any mistake let me know about it, and if there is some confusion because i am truly not confident.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be feeling more confident in your answer, as it is easily checked against the PDE and the initial condition.

From
$$u(t,x)=5e^{-(x-4t)^2} \tag{*}$$

use the chain rule to compute the partial derivatives as

$$\begin{align}
u_t=u\frac{\partial}{\partial t}[-(x-4t)^2]&=8(x-4t)u \\[1em]
u_x=u\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[-(x-4t)^2]&=-2(x-4t)u
\end{align}$$
so we have identically that $u_t+4u_x=0$ for all $x,t$.

To check the initial condition substitute $t=0$ into (*) to get:

$$u(0,x)=5e^{-(x-0)^2}=5e^{-x^2}$$
as required.